# Trigger featherlight.js by clicking image without <a> element

Tags: featherlight.js

Is there a way to get featherlight.js to trigger on an image itself, as opposed to a surrounding  link?

For example, I'm trying this:

`$('img.pop').featherlight($(this));`

But getting an error:

> a.cloneNode is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Should not be a problem. The problem is probably what is `this` in your code above. That's why my advice to anyone ever reporting a problem is to produce a working example.